# Fusionar angular y angularjs

Tags: soporte, etiquetas

> **Esta pregunta tiene una discusión más reciente en
>   [¿Que tal si re-etiquetamos Angular y AngularJS?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2934/127)**

Las etiquetas [angular](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) y [angularjs](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) deberian ser funcionadas, quiza quedando [angular](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) como principal.

De igual menera [angular2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2) y [angularjs-2.0](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-2.0) ambas se refieren a lo mismo.

Pero, deberían ser englobadas en [angular2.x](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2.x) o simplemente [angular2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2) como se hace en otras etiquetas

Comment: Este sinónimo fue revertido. Propongo como duplicado de [¿Que tal si re-etiquetamos Angular y AngularJS?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2934/127) para que quede registro de los sinónimos actuales.

Comment: Me imagino que estarás contento con que finalmente se implementó el cambio y que ahora todas las diferentes versiones están más unificadas... Lo que estuve observando es que, al revertir el sinónimo [tag:angularjs] ← [tag:angular], se generó algo de lío, dejando a algunas preguntas mal etiquetadas... Sería bueno que alguien de la comunidad de Angular tome las riendas para ordenar un poco esas preguntas que quedaron mal, probablemente acompañando con una publicación en Meta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gracias por el aporte @jasilva. Los sinónimos fueron creados. Pueden verificar los resultados. Avísenme si hay algún inconveniente luego de la combinación y los sinónimos realizados.

Comment: Parece que todo esta correcto :)

Answer (score 3):

No me parece adecuado:

- AngularJS y Angular son dos frameworks totalmente distintos, uno se hizo con Javascript y el segundo sus fuentes son en Typescript.
- Angular2 es un mal nombre porque no hay ningún framework con ese nombre. Si aceptamos que para cada versión de angular necesitamos un tag (aunque de momento angular v2 y angular v4 son muy compatibles) creo que sería mejor establecer un estándar para todos los tags que lleven número de version, quizá sería mejor algo como [angular-v2.x](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-v2.x) y [angular-v4.x](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-v4.x) (gracias por el aporte en elos comentarios, @Rubén)
- En SO [angular](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) y [angularjs](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) hacen referencia a los dos frameworks, quienes usamos indistintamente la versión inglesa y española nos vamos a confundir bastante.

Comment: Mas que un problema, yo creo que es apropiado tener un etiqueta por cada versión mayor porque no todo mundo quiere o puede usar la versión más reciente.

Answer (score 2):

Estoy totalmente de acuerdo, sólo que en `SO eng` la etiqueta principal es `angularjs`, propongo dejarlo igual.

Ahora con la otra debería ser `angular2` para todo.

Comment: me parece bien usar `angularjs` mientras se haga la fusión

Comment: Se esta mezclando preguntas de Angular y AngularJS debido a este cambio: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1495/diferenciar-las-etiquetas-angular-y-angularjs

Comment: Se debe eliminar "JS" de las etiquetas relacionadas con Angular

Comment: Angular y Angular JS sería lo correcto. Angular es Angular, sea la versión que sea a partir de la 2.0 y Angular JS es angular 1.X antes de la 2.0

Es erroneo decir Angular 2 o Angular 4, etc. Lo correcto es Angular o AngularJS