# Diferenciar las etiquetas Angular y AngularJS

Tags: soporte, etiquetas

### Antecedentes

El año pasado se propuso [fusionar las etiquetas Angular y AngularJs](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/529/fusionar-angular-y-angularjs) y dicha modificación fue aceptada; sin embargo a la luz de la adopción del [Versionado Semántico](http://semver.org/) por parte del equipo de desarrollo del Framework, se requiere diferenciar las etiquetas cuya fusión se aprobó el año pasado.

### Movimientos solicitados

1. El primer movimiento consiste en diferenciar las etiquetas [angularjs](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) para referirse a a [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/)  (AngularJS 1.x) de la etiqueta **[angular](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular)** que se refiere al framework [Angular](https://angular.io/)
2. El segundo movimiento se refiere a la dirigir las etiquetas `angular2` y `angularjs-2.0` a la etiqueta **[angular](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular)**.
3. Por último, modificar la wiki de la etiqueta [angular](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular).

### Motivación

- [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) usa JavaScript como lenguaje para desarrollar aplicaciones
- [Angular](https://angular.io/) utiliza TypeScript o Dart lo que lo hace diferente de su predecesor
- La etiqueta [angularjs-2.0](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-2.0) ya no tiene sentido, debido a que la adopción de [semver](https://angularjs.org/) hace irrelevantes la numeración (salvo los casos previstos de obsolescencia). Para ampliar este punto, Angular pasará en la siguiente versión a ser la 4.0 sin pasar por la rama 3.
- La [**marca**](https://angular.io/presskit.html) ha cambiado a Angular de forma oficial.

Comment: No sería la primera vez que un lenguaje, framework, etc, evoluciona en otro distinto y se siguen usando ambos. Como C y C++. Tiene sentido separarlas. Cuando dices que AngularJS-2.0 ya no tienen sentido, ¿te refieres a dejarla como sinónimo de Angular o a otra cosa?

Comment: Si, a eso me refiero, ese es el movimiento 2 que solicito.

Comment: Los errores son imposibles de evitar. Como no existe forma de asegurar que la gente lea las orientaciones de uso, y cuando lo hacen, no hay forma de asegurar la comprensión, y como no hay forma de obligarlos a usar esa o cualquier etiqueta que deseen, solo podemos esperar que lean las orientaciones de uso y que las usen correctamente. Con respecto a las preguntas que ya están etiquetadas, no creo que haya que hacer nada en este momento, porque no hay recursos suficientes para revisar todas esas preguntas.

Comment: Se estan mezclando preguntas de Angular y AngularJS en la etiqueta AngularJS-2.0, son frameworks diferentes y esto afecta a la calidad de las respuestas del sitio, creo que el un tema que habría que solucionar lo antes posible. Bajo mi opinión la etiqueta AngularJS-2.0 deberia ser solo AngularJS ya que este framework no ha llegado a la versión 2.0, esta etiqueta contiene una denominación erronea que hace que los usuarios piensen que se refiere a Angular o AngularJS indistintamente.

Comment: Creo que modificar los nombres de las etiquetas tal y como sugiere @toledano ayudaría a que la gente comprendiera mejor dónde ha de etiquetar su pregunta.

La etiqueta AngularJS-2.0 No tiene sentido y distrae ya que los poco duchos en el tema pueden interpretarlo como la versión 1.X de Angular (por el JS) o por la versión 2 del framework (Angular)

Comment: Adjunto un enlace del blog oficial de Angular explicando la diferencia entre Angular y Angular JS y porque no ha de utilizarse ningún número para referirse al primero. Ampliando así la ifnormación dad por @toledano
http://angularjs.blogspot.com.es/2016/12/ok-let-me-explain-its-going-to-be.html

Comment: Angular va por la versión 4 actualmente, en Google necesitas escribir "angular4" para obtener información al día de este framework. Usar [tag:AngularJS-2] cada día que pasa es más obsoleto, y tenerlo fusionado on [tag:angular] no ayuda mucho

Comment: Esto fue implementado recién gracias a lois6b, siguiendo la propuesta de [¿Que tal si re-etiquetamos Angular y AngularJS?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2934/127). Propongo como duplicada para dejar constancia del estado actual de los sinónimos.