# Mezclar todas las etiquetas [angular2X] en [angular]

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

Actualmente hay etiquetas como

- [`angularjs-2.0`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-2.0) (sinónimo `angular2`)
- [`angular4`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular4) (sin sinónimos)
- [`angular5`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular5)(sin sinónimos)

... y así otras más que tributan a la versión reescrita del framework [AngularJS (1.x)](https://angularjs.org/), es decir [Angular (2+)](https://angular.io/).

A este paso a medida que sigan saliendo versiones de Angular, seguirán apareciendo etiquetas como `angular6`, `angular7` y asi sucesivamente.

Actualmente ya es difícil seguir el contenido relacionado con Angular(2+) debido a la cantidad de etiquetas que tributan a este tema, así que cuando vayan apareciendo esas otras etiquetas no imagino cuan más difícil será.

¿Podría alguien, moderador o usuario con privilegios mezclar estas etiquetas que tributan a Angular (versión 2 o superior) en una sola (`angular` recomendada) y poner las otras como sinónimos, o aplicar alguna variante para que sea más facil seguir todos los posts que se publican acerca de [Angular](https://angular.io/)?

Comment: No frecuento las preguntas de Angular, pero te recomiendo leer primero las otras publicaciones que se hicieron en Meta sobre este tema... ¿No estás diciendo lo mismo que en [¿Que tal si re-etiquetamos Angular y AngularJS?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2934/127), o que en [Diferenciar las etiquetas Angular y AngularJS](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1495/127)?

Comment: Por otro lado, para listar todas las preguntas, se puede buscar por [`[angular*]`](http://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bangular*%5D).

Comment: Correcto @Mariano. No habia visto estas preguntas. Muchas gracias. Marcare esta como duplicda

Comment: Oh, perfecto eso de `[angular*]`!

Comment: Esto ya está implementado según la propuesta de [¿Que tal si re-etiquetamos Angular y AngularJS?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2934/127), usando como etiquetas principales [tag:angularjs] y [tag:angular]