# ¿Que tal si re-etiquetamos Angular y AngularJS?

Tags: soporte, estado-completado, etiquetas, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

Existen varias etiquetas de `Angular`, la cuales hasta confunden, ej.:

[angularjs](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) y [angularjs-2.0](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-2.0)

No existe `AngularJS 2.0`, sería acaso `Angular 2`, pero aún así no lo especificaría.

Tenemos ya en meta esta propuesta [Diferenciar las etiquetas Angular y AngularJS](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1495/diferenciar-las-etiquetas-angular-y-angularjs)
 pero lo que veo no se ha hecho aún nada al respecto.

Propongo **una vez más**:

Dejar [angularjs](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) para las versiones 1.x

y estás etiquetas:

- [angularjs-2.0](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-2.0)
- [angular4](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular4)
- [angularjs-4.0](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-4.0)
- [angular-v2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-v2)
- [angular2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2)

fusionarlo a la etiqueta [angular](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) para los restos de versiones `(2-5)`.

o

poner con las versiones para ser más especifico:

- [angular2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2)
- [angular4](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular4)
- [angular5](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular5)

ya que existe también una etiqueta: [angular2-template](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2-template)

¿Como lo veis?

Comment: Yo no fusionaría todas las versiones de angular en una sola etiqueta `angular` ya que cada versión tiene sus peculiaridades. En cambio, si que pondría un formato como el que dices de `angular2`, `angular4`, etc... para resolver las dudas de esas versiones concretas.

Comment: No sé cuantas veces se ha pedido ya, pero tienes mi apoyo, una vez más. Pero creo que @FranciscoRomero tiene razón, cada versión añade algo y la retrocompatibilidad no es del 100%

Comment: @PabloLozano - En SOen está el padre (master) angularjs y angular lo demás son sinónimos... un ejemplo las versiones de PHP.. no lo vería lógico poner `PHP5.4`, `PHP5.5`, `PHP5.6`etc... cual cada uno tiene cambios no compatibles a las versiones anteriores... esa es mi humilde opinión

Comment: @aldanux Pero de C++ hay unas cuantas y me parece que no son sinónimos (c++11, c++14, c++98...)... quizá sea un caso distinto por ser especificaciones de un lenguaje

Comment: al igual que @PabloLozano he pedido esto, es lo mejor y angular es una forma difefrente de angularjs

Comment: aldanux gracias a @lois6b que generó los sinónimos, esto ya quedó implementado... Sería bueno marcar la respuesta más votada como aceptada y quizás ver que la comunidad revise que las preguntas queden bien etiquetadas... quizás acompañando con una publicación en Meta. ¿Te parece?

Comment: Falta añadir angular5, angular6, angular 7, angular8... y en unos meses supongo que angular9

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Propuesta #1

**Concepto:** Las etiquetas principales serían, según la versión de Angular:

- Versión 1.x: [angularjs](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs)
- Versión 2+: [angular](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular)

Por lo tanto, se deberían eliminar algunos sinónimos y generar otros nuevos.

**Eliminar** el sinónimo:

1. [angularjs](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) ← [angular](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular)

**Generar** los sinónimos:

1. [angular](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) ← [angularjs-2.0](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-2.0)
2. [angular](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) ← [angular4](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular4)
3. [angular](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) ← [angularjs-4.0](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-4.0)

**Mantener** el sinónimo:

1. [angularjs-2.0](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-2.0) ← [angular2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2)
   (que con el cambio descrito arriba, ambas empezarían a apuntar a [angular](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular))

> Esta propuesta sigue la misma lógica que en SO
>   (ver [sinónimos de angular](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/angular/synonyms) y [sinónimos de angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/angularjs/synonyms))

Comment: Me costaba un poco entender todos los sinónimos que estabas proponiendo, y creo que así queda un poco más claro... No dudes en revertir o modificar si hay algo en lo que me haya equivocado

Comment: Muchas gracias @Mariano - Me parece estupendo! Aprovecho de saludar y que hecho un poco de menos esto todo... espero volver pronto! ;)

Comment: @aldanux ya está implementado esto. Sin embargo, el sistema no deja que se haga `angular <- angularjs-2.0 <- angular2` asi que quité el `angularjs-2.0 <- angular2` para que ambas apunten a `angular`:  https://i.imgur.com/ebwPQMu.png

Answer (score -1):

## Propuesta #2

Crear las etiquetas `master` para diferenciar las versiones de `angular`:

- `1.x` → [angularjs](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs)
- `2.x` → [angular2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2)
- `4.x` → [angular4](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular4)
- `5.x` → [angular5](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular5)

Esta fusión está mal y debe ser eliminada:

[angularjs](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) ← [angular](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular)

Sinónimos creados:

[angularjs-2.0](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-2.0) ← [angular2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2)

cambiarlo a:

[angular2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2) ← [angularjs-2.0](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-2.0)

Crear nuevo sinónimo:

[angular4](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular4) ← [angularjs-4.0](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-4.0)