# Angular ya puede etiquetarse bien

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, llamada-a-la-accion

Recientemente se arregló un problema importantísimo que tenían las etiquetas de Angular.
Se completó el pedido de [¿Que tal si re-etiquetamos Angular y AngularJS?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2934/127).

Esto significa que se eliminó el sinónimo [angularjs](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) ← [angular](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) que hacía que las preguntas de Angular quedaran mal etiquetadas.

Entonces ahora las etiquetas principales son, según la versión de Angular:

- Versión 1.x: [angularjs](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs)
- Versión 2+: [angular](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular)

---

Pero en una primera instancia tiene asociado un problema: muchas de las preguntas de Angular aún siguen etiquetadas como AngularJS. Sería bueno que la comunidad que frecuenta estas etiquetas esté atenta para corregir reetiquetando todas las preguntas que puedan como corresponde.

Comment: De hecho, yo no uso Angular, pero viendo el problema que se estaba generando me involucré... Quien pueda ayudar, se agradece enormemente.