# ¿Es conveniente crear sinónimos de etiquetas para Angular y ajustar las existentes?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

Actualmente angular tiene las etiquetas [angular4](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular4), [angularjs-4.0](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-4.0), [angularjs-2.0](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-2.0) y [angular2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2) como sinónimos. Pero encuentro algunos problemas con esto:

- [angularjs-2.0](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-2.0) No existe. Si es `angularjs` no debería ser 2, son versiones completamente diferentes incompatibles entre sí. (En mi opinion, `angular` deberia haber empezado desde 1 de nuevo, pero no es asi)
- [angularjs-4.0](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-4.0) El mismo caso anterior.

Esto me aparece en la seccion de [sinonimos de etiqueta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/angularjs/synonyms):

> Es difícil encontrar preguntas con etiquetas incorrectas y responder a
>   dichas preguntas. Si conoces frases o palabras alternativas comunes
>   para esta etiqueta, agrégalas aquí de modo que podamos corregirlas
>   automáticamente en el futuro. Por ejemplo, puedes sugerir “bici” como
>   sinónimo de bicicleta o “calcetín” para calcetines.

Segun el ejemplo dado usar [angularjs-4.0](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-4.0) equivaldría a [bici-moto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bici-moto) lo cual no cumple la definición de un [sinónimo](https://dle.rae.es/sin%C3%B3nimo) de la RAE.

Tambien creo que sería conveniente agregar como sinónimos las versiones de la 3 a la 9 de esta manera:

- [angular3](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular3)
- [angular4](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular4)
- [angular5](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular5)
- [angular6](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular6)
- [angular7](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular7)
- [angular8](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular8)
- [angular9](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular9)

Es muy común encontrarme con esas etiquetas (aunque `angular` no tiene tantas preguntas).

Comment: En la discusión de Meta [¿Que tal si re-etiquetamos Angular y AngularJS?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2943/83) se decidió usar Versión 1.x  [tag:angularjs] y versiones 2+ [tag:angular]. No conozco el detalle de Angular, pero es bueno tener presente que allí hubo un debate que convendría leer.

Comment: La clave aquí es que a Angular 1 se le llama Angular JS y a Angular 2+ se le llama Angular a secas. Por tanto entiendo que la solución consiste en eliminar los sinónimos con `js` en las versiones 2+.

Comment: Son tecnologías INCOMPATIBLES!!!!!! De hecho, por favor, revisad los problemas que causa dicha diferencia. ANGULARJS y ANGULAR2.X no funcionan igual!!! No son lo mismo!!! 

https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4717/pregunta-dupplicada-no-es-duplicada